# Kotlin: Higher Order Function recursive, iterative and with fold

Tags: recursion, kotlin, iteration, higher-order-functions

I'm learning Kotlin and functional programming. I have to implement own functions for a sealed class. One of the functions should be created in three different ways: recursive, iterative and with the use of the fold function. I picked the `any()` function.

The only idea I had after a lot of research is to create a tailrec function and to use fold inside the function:

```
fun <T> anyFold (list: MyList<T>, p: (T) -> Boolean)  {
tailrec fun <R> fold (list : MyList<T>, init: R, transform: (R, T) -> R) : Boolean {
    when (list) {
        is MyList.Node -> fold(list.tail, transform(init,list.head),transform)
        is MyList.Nil -> init
    }
    return fold(list, init, transform)

}
```

}

But I think this is not the way it should be done as the outcome is `AnyFold kotlin.Unit`.

Now I'm looking for a different approach. Is there any way to create the any function by mapping it to the fold function? Ideas are very welcome.

Comment: What you need is to determine what to pass instead of `init` and `transform`, so it will be `fun <T> anyFold (list: MyList<T>, p: (T) -> Boolean) = fold(list, ???, ???)`.

Comment: Your version only defines `fold` and doesn't use it.

Comment: Ok. Now I've got:
fun <T> anyfold (list:MyList<T>, p:(T)-> Boolean) = folding(list, p, ???). p is init. But what to pass for transform instead?

Comment: No, `init` shouldn't be `p`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your notation:

```
fun <T> anyFold(list: List<T>, p: (T) -> Boolean): Boolean =
    list.fold(false, { acc, element -> acc || p(element) })


fun main() {
    println(  anyFold( listOf(1,2,3,4,5)) {it < 5 }) // true
    println(  anyFold( listOf(1,2,3,4,5)) {it > 5 }) // false
}
```